# Heroku app can't contact EC2 web service. Fails with getaddrinfo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns

We have a job which runs hourly and makes about 500 api calls to a web services that we host on EC2. Occasionally we'll see the first few api calls succeed and the rest fail with

```
Organization#refresh_active_fs_project failed with SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
```

Here's an output from our logs. You can see some success then failure.

```
2013-04-17T22:55:19.562371+00:00 app[worker.2]: [Worker(host:0a43f011-6062-4744-9213-b836df0d9800 pid:2)] Organization#refresh_active_fs_project completed after 0.0613

2013-04-17T22:55:19.562371+00:00 app[worker.2]: [Worker(host:0a43f011-6062-4744-9213-b836df0d9800 pid:2)] Organization#refresh_active_fs_project failed with SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known - 0 failed attempts

2013-04-17T22:55:19.562621+00:00 app[worker.2]: [Worker(host:0a43f011-6062-4744-9213-b836df0d9800 pid:2)] Organization#refresh_active_fs_project failed with SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known - 0 failed attempts

2013-04-17T22:55:19.562871+00:00 app[worker.2]: [Worker(host:0a43f011-6062-4744-9213-b836df0d9800 pid:2)] Organization#refresh_active_fs_project failed with SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known - 0 failed attempts
```

I wrote into Heroku support about this before and we couldn't come up with much besides jiggling our EC2 security groups. They confirmed that we aren't being throttled or anything.

The problem is intermittent. We thought it may have something to do with the speed of the calls, but the calls sometime fail out of nowhere when we call then one-off. Otherwise, our EC2 services run and serve requests just fine.

I don't know much about DNS, so if the problem is rooted there then guidance would be appreciated.